# specifying corAR1 structure in GAMM

Tags: r, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a dataset with two sites (A and B) that include multiple observation from across years, but not every year is sampled at each site (nor are the observations balanced across years).
For example, at site A there is data from 20 years (across a 30 year period), with anywhere from 10-103 observations/year.

The acf and pacf plots show some autocorrelation for one of the two sites (example below).

I've been using a gam to model changes in time:

```
gam(RO ~ s(YEAR) + s(YEAR, SITE, bs = "sz"))
```

However, I'd like to use `gamm` instead and add a correlation structure. Ideally this would be nested within site, but I have not had any success getting any of my attempted structures to run:

```r
gamm(RO ~ s(YEAR) + s(YEAR, SITE, bs = "sz"), 
    correlation = corAR1(form = ~ YEAR | SITE))
    Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[i]], ...) : 
      covariate must have unique values within groups 
       for "corAR1" objects
    In addition: Warning message:
    In gam.side(sm, X, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) :
      model has repeated 1-d smooths of same variable.

    gamm(RO ~ s(YEAR) + s(YEAR, SITE, bs = "sz"), 
     correlation = corAR1(form = ~ YEAR))
    Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[i]], ...) : 
      covariate must have unique values within groups for "corAR1" objects
    In addition: Warning message:
    In gam.side(sm, X, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) :
      model has repeated 1-d smooths of same variable.
```

I've also tried creating a separate time variable with the years numbered in order. For example, if there is data in 1970, 1971, and 1973, these are numbered as 1, 2, and 4.

```r
gamm(RO ~ s(YEAR) + s(YEAR, SITE, bs = "sz"), 
    correlation = corAR1(form = ~ time))
    Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[i]], ...) : 
      covariate must have unique values within groups 
    for "corAR1" objects
    In addition: Warning message:
    In gam.side(sm, X, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) 
    :
      model has repeated 1-d smooths of same variable.
```

And lastly, I've created another time variable with the years numbered, but I ignore years without data in the numbering. For example, if there is data (for at least 1 site) in 1970, 1971, and 1973, these are numbered as 1, 2, and 3.

```r
gamm(RO ~ s(YEAR) + s(YEAR, SITE, bs = "sz"), 
    correlation = corAR1(form = ~ seqtime))
    Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[i]], ...) : 
      covariate must have unique values within groups 
    for "corAR1" objects
    In addition: Warning message:
    In gam.side(sm, X, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) 
    :
      model has repeated 1-d smooths of same variable.
```

**What am I missing?**

*acf plot for site = A

[image]

*acf plot for site = B*

[image]

Comment: From a practical point of view, even if you figure out the correct `corFoo()` call, it won't do anything as `correlation` is *not* an argument to `gam()`. It only works with `gamm()`...

Comment: @GavinSimpson, yup, my copy paste error.  those should all be gamm's not gam's.  the error message is the same though.

Comment: You're going to need `correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ time | SITE)` where `time` is some variable that indexes the actual time points such that the gaps are preserved. Your data don't sound like they're regularly spaced so a continuous time AR(1) is an option, as is treating time as a 1D spatial process and using one of the spatial correlation structures with a constant `y` coordinate.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson. Just so I understand the 'evenly spaced" piece, my year variable as it currently is, preserves the gaps (no values for years without data), but it doesn't start at 0 or 1. Will that work? Also, there are multiple measures of RO in each year and site combination. Is that an issue with corCAR1?  I can't order these within a year.